# How to use C# as Object Oriented Design?

Tags: c#

This probably has already been asked, sorry, but is C# an object-oriented language like Java? It's been a while since I worked in C++, but I just wanted to check: can I make multiple classes and use them as objects in the same Visual Studio project? And would these be .cs files? e.g. Playback_Adjuster.cs, Gesture_Control.cs, Audio_File.cs?

Thanks!

Comment: You can use separate file for each class, but you may also put many classes into one file. It's up to you. You can also "distribute"/"slice" one class to many files by using `partial class` statement. Using one class for Form/Window can put interface related objects in one and logic in another file.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, C# is fully Object Oriented. You can read about it here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460654.aspx

Additionally, C# files typically have a .cs extension, as you mentioned. You can use multiple classes in the same project - just like other OO languages. In my experience, I've found C# and Java to be actually quite similar in many respects - with differences, of course.